# issue with parsing/encoding strings in csv in s3 with lambda (python)

Tags: python, csv, parsing, lambda, encoding

I wrote a program in python in Lambda to read a CSV from S3, and then add some information and store it into another CSV in S3.

The initial line in the original CSV is like this:

```
2020-04-23 00:00:00,pass,7481.15000000,7480.12000000
```

When I try to read, add some information, and store it into a second CSV in S3, it comes out like this:

```
"b'[2020-04-21 00:00:00,pass],[2020-04-21 00:00:00,pass],[2020-04-21 00:00:00,pass],[2020-04-22 00:00:00,pass,7126.77000000,7126.56000000]\r'",b'',"[b'2020-04-23 00:00:00,pass,7481.15000000,7480.12000000\r', b'']"
```

So obviously with the `b'` and `\r''b''`

Code looks like this:

```
def fetch_data_from_s3(filename):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    csvfile = s3.get_object(Bucket='thisbuckername', Key=filename)
    csvcontent = csvfile['Body'].read().split(b'\n')
    return csvcontent

def write_data_to_s3(filename, row):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    csvio = io.StringIO()
    writer = csv.writer(csvio)
    writer.writerow(row)
    s3.put_object(Body=csvio.getvalue(), ContentType='text/csv', Bucket='thisbucketname', Key=filename)
    csvio.close()

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    historical = fetch_data_from_s3('compiled.csv')
    last = fetch_data_from_s3('original.csv')
    historical.append(last)
    write_data_to_s3('compiled.csv', historical)
```

Is there something wrong with encoding? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Normally a "b'stuff'" shows up when a file has been open'd for writing strings, but the data being sent is bytes. Is there a reason your using io.StringIO() instead of Bytes?

```
#Example
str(b'stuff')
```

Many editors and file types end lines with a "\r\n", which is a carriage return symbol and a newline symbol. This happens for many reason especially when you have internet files, or files from both windows and linux being converted. In windows there is only one byte that means "move curser down and go to the beginning of the line", in linux there are two bytes "\n" (move curser down) and "\r" (move curser to beginning of line". This is why in linux you can overwrite a printed line (in most terminals):

```
for i in range(1000000):
    print(i,end='\r')
```

You should be using str.strip() to ensure you don't have any trailing "\r" or "\n". Here is an example:

```
lines = [line.strip() for line in open(file).readlines()]
```